# Getting "undefined" in the first time using http .get() in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services

I'm trying to retrieve data from and endpoint in Angular.
This is the service:

```
export class VideosService {
result;
constructor(private http: Http, public router: Router) { }

getVideos() {
    this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/videos?sessionId=' + localStorage.getItem('sessionId'))
        .map(response => response.json())
        .subscribe(result => this.result = result);
        localStorage.setItem('videos', this.result);
        console.log(localStorage);
}
```

It works everytime EXCEPT the first one. The first one I've got "undefined" and the other one's I get the actual object.

What I'm doing wrong?
Thnks!

Comment: *the other one's I get the actual object* No, you get the **previous** object.

Comment: Yes I can see it now. Thank you sir

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code:

```
.subscribe(result => this.result = result);
localStorage.setItem('videos', this.result);
```

The code `localStorage.setItem('videos', this.result);` will execute *before* `.subscribe(result => this.result = result);`.

## Fix

Lookup async programming JavaScript or simply:

```
.subscribe(result => {this.result = result;   localStorage.setItem('videos', this.result);});
```

Comment: Exactly, you should also brush up on RxJS Observers, Luis.